# Robocopy - change language

Tags: windows, robocopy

Is there a way to change the output language or robocopy?
I have a lot of scripts that run and I find a script that extracts only important info from the output but works only in english which isn't the default language on my computer.

Many thanks!

Comment: I think this is covered here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/142812/temporarily-change-language-for-terminal-messages-warnings-errors

Comment: @StanTastic robocopy is (as far as I know) windows only. So I'm not sure anything linked to in the askubutu stackexchange would be helpful.

Comment: rex you are right. is a windows-only tools for copying/sync folder.
any other idea?